# Connecting Salesforce with Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, salesforce, flash-builder

I am trying to Connecting Salesforce with Adobe Air Application i.e. pulling data from Sales force to the AIR application. I tried this with Developerforce toolkit. But its not working. I tried the example from this following reference http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Taking_Data_Offline_Using_Adobe_AIR . Please help me in this. And also please tell me is there any way to connect salesforce with AIR application.
Note: Im using Flashbuilder as IDE.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the OAuth code from the provided toolkit and then to use the Rest API with the various AIR HTTP classes to do the rest yourself, there's libraries available for parsing the JSON to local actionscript objects.